# Python attribut error

Tags: python, import, attributes

I try to use the "pygubu" module. I installed it via pip.

I can import it in my script but `pygubu.Builder()` throws an attribute error.

If I do import it via console and start the script afterwards. There is no error and the script runs.

In the internet I found a wrong pythonpath could be the problem but I checked it, the pythonpath is pointing to the installation folder.

Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you add `import pygubu` at the beginning of your Python file?

Comment: did you happen to name your script "pygubu.py"?

Comment: yes i named my script pygubu.py.... I changed it and it worked, thanks, i will add it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
The problem was my script was named "pygubu.py"(same as the module i tried to import), after renaming it, everything worked. Thanks to Bryan Oakley for that info.